# App is working fine in usb debug mode, but when i generate Signed APK and install it, its not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, apk

I have tried different solutions like giving INTERNET PERMISION in manifest file  && Turning off PROGUARD by  useProguard false

My app name: SMS_VOICE_NOTIFICATION

My app description: so whenever my phone  receive an SMS it reads out the smsbody using Text-to-Speech, For this im using foreground service because if i use background service my system kills it after some Time.

In debug mode everything is working great, but when I start generating signed apk the broadcast receiver is not working just the UI part is working

I have registered the Broadcast Receiver like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MyReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    receiver = new MyReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiver,intentFilter);
    super.onStart();
}
```

build.gradle(app)

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.smsassistsigiri"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
    resConfigs "en"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

My build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.smsassistsigiri"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.1"
    resConfigs "en"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

My Broadcast receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static  final String SMS_RECEIVED =  "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
//TODO:Implement whats app text to speech
public static final String WHATS_APP_RECEIVED = "";
private static final String TAG = "SmsBroadcastReceiver";
String msg,PhoneNo = "";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG,"INTENT RECEIVED:"+intent.getAction());
    //if(intent.getAction()==SMS_RECEIVED){
      if(intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)){
        //Retrieve  a map of extended data from the intent
        Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(dataBundle!=null){
            //creating a PDU (PROTOCOL DATA UNIT)
            Object[]  mypdu = (Object[]) dataBundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] message = new SmsMessage[mypdu.length];
            for(int i=0;i<mypdu.length;i++){
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                    //API leve  > than 23
                    String format = dataBundle.getString("format");
                    message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mypdu[i],format);
                }
                else{
                    message[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])mypdu[i]);
                }
                msg = message[i].getMessageBody();
                PhoneNo = message[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }

            SmsService instance = SmsService.getInstance();
            //if startservice button is not pressed then if we get a message then instance will be null so that's why we need to check for null
            if(instance!=null){
                instance.speak(msg);
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Message: "+msg+" \nNumber: "+PhoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Data bundle is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
      else {
          Log.e("SMSNOTRECEIVED","SMSNOTRECEIVED");
      }
}
```

}

MainifestFile

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SMSAssist">
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" ></action>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".SmsService"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

While making signed android build obfuscation is applied which sometimes removes the necessary parts of your application code. So, attach the test device in case you are not working with an emulator and carefully watch the logcat where you can see the issue where application code is breaking.
Now you need to add exceptional cases where you don't want to obfuscate your code. For this :

- Open proguard-rules.pro file which is under your app directory somewhere below build.gradle file.
- Now add exceptional cases by adding classes causing crashes like this:

  `-keep public class com.app.YourActivtyOrFragment { public <methods>; public <fields>; }`

Comment: but i have Turned off Proguard Then the apk should work fine right ?
it should not break my code if it is turned off?

Comment: @sigri Yes, it should not, then please share error logs, also are you installing it directly from build variants in android studio or firstly making an apk and then sending it to your device and installing over there?

Comment: I'm making an apk then sending it to my phone using what's app web and installing it on my phone

Comment: okay so now when you install it does it crashes on start or you are not even able to install it? Also any logcat traces?

Comment: There is no problem while installing and almost every ui part is working fine, except broadcast receiver is not being able to work

Answer (score 0):

Is your app registered as the device's default SMS or assistant handler? You're no longer able to use permissions like READ_SMS unless your app is the default handler:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10208820?visit_id=637627208051926352-3034324628&rd=1#zippy=%2Cpermitted-uses-of-the-sms-and-call-log-permissions